# async.queue concurrent tasks

Tags: node.js, async.js

I am using `async.queue` to ensure that certain file copies in a service happen at most `n` concurrently, but watching the files copy sometimes I see a lot more than what the queue allows. Does anyone see something I may have missed in the below implementation?

```
createQueue(limit: number) {
    let self = this;
    return async.queue(function(cmdObj, callback) {
      console.log("Beginning copy");
      let cmd = cmdObj.cmd;
      let args = cmdObj.args;
      let request = cmdObj.req;
      request.state = State.IN_PROGRESS;
      self.reportStatus(request.destination);
      const proc = spawn(cmd, args); //uses an rsync command upstream
      proc.on("close", code => {
        if (code !== 0) {
          request.state = State.ERRORED;
          self.reportStatus(request.destination); // these just report to the caller
          statusMap.delete(request.destination);
        } else {
          fs.rename(request.destination + ".part", request.destination);
          request.state = State.COMPLETED;
          self.reportStatus(request.destination); // same here
          statusMap.delete(request.destination);
        }
        callback();
      });
      proc.on("error", err => {
        console.error("COPY ERR: " + err);
      });
    }, limit); // limit here, for example, may be two, but I see four copies concurrently
  }
```

EDIT:
I now believe this is a side effect of the rest of the system...queues being cleared and reinitialized AFTER copies have started...so when new items are added to the reinitialized queues, they kick off immediately, as the system has no idea if something has been handed off to userland and is currently running.

Comment: can you show how you push things onto the queue? I assume this call is only called once then the returned queue is used.

Comment: That's correct. I'm working on singling out the problem, but I think it is user error. I think I am blitzing that queue at the wrong time, tasks are already happening, a new queue is created that is unaware of the tasks in progress, so it spawns N new tasks. if it works, I'll just add it as an answer so it isn't an orphaned question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this was user error...PEBCAK! Posting the solution more as a cautionary tale:

The queues above were working as designed, but I had an endpoint for the calling server to clear the queues as necessary; the problem was i was using `kill()` and re-initializing the queues, losing all track of any jobs in progress and their callbacks. As soon as a new item hit the fresh queue, it would think nothing was happening and spawn a new copy process. I resolved by using `remove` to clear the queues instead of re-initializing.